# Jenkins multijob show failed when all sub jobs succeed

Tags: jenkins

I have a multijob which has 6 child job. During test, I found that the multijob always show failed even all sub jobs succeed. The error message is:

```
Finished Build : 1.0.0.1 of Job : Sub_Job_6 with status : SUCCESS
FATAL: Channel "unknown": Remote call on JNLP4-connect connection from build_machine/10.224.113.202:51903 failed. The channel is closing down or has closed down
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.NetworkLayer.onRecvClosed(NetworkLayer.java:154)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.NIONetworkLayer.ready(NIONetworkLayer.java:179)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.IOHub$OnReady.run(IOHub.java:789)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused: hudson.remoting.ChannelClosedException: Channel "unknown": Remote call on JNLP4-connect connection from build_machine/10.224.113.202:51903 failed. The channel is closing down or has closed down
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:945)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher.kill(Launcher.java:1078)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:510)
    at com.tikal.jenkins.plugins.multijob.MultiJobBuild$MultiJobRunnerImpl.run(MultiJobBuild.java:148)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1727)
    at com.tikal.jenkins.plugins.multijob.MultiJobBuild.run(MultiJobBuild.java:76)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Please provide more info about your job setup, slaves, etc. Meanwhile, look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20136338/jenkins-issue-hudson-remoting-channelclosedexception-channel-is-already-closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause. One of my sub job is to power off, power on the build machine( a reboot actually). After reboot, Jenkins client will re-connect to Jenkins server. The server may think it's a new conversation, the old one has stopped with some exception. So the final result will show failed.
After I removed this sub job, the multijob showed success finally.